# How to resize dynamic chart in javascript to redraw on window resize

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a dynamic chart I created:

Working demo: http://codepen.io/codeChris/pen/MwWmgN

```
$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([{
title: "Appointment Calls",
value: 49,
color: "#ee7600"
}, {
title: "Non-Appointment Calls",
value: 47,
color: "#6e3671"
}]);
});.... // the animation is long, so I cut it out of the question
```

How do I add the ability to redraw this chart when the widow resizes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Highcharts redraw on windows resize is default behavior - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-innersize-80px/). It doesn't look like you are using Highcharts...

Comment: You are right.  My mistake.  I edited the question.